# What's a good way to remove the 2nd last character of string?

Tags: java

What's a concise way to remove the 2nd last character of string?

e.g. "abcde" becomes "abce"

there is no need to check that the string is long enough.

Comment: How are you defining "good"? Best performance? Fewest lines of code? Easiest to understand?

Comment: That's not really how Stack Overflow works... we strive for specificity here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return new StringBuilder(str)
  .deleteCharAt(str.length() - 2)
  .toString();
```

I suspect that this is about as fast, compact, and understandable as it'll get.

Answer (score 2):

Take all characters except last two, take the last one and concatenate them. Code is trivial assuming the string is at least 2 characters. [Hint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = "abcde";
int length = input.size();
String result = input.substring(0, length  - 2) + input.substring(length, length);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public String getAllButSecondLast(final String input)
{
  return input.substring(0, input.length() - 2) + input.charAt(input.length() - 1);

}
```

Of course this does not provide null checking or length checking (must be at least 2 characters).

Answer (score 1):

```
String test = "abcde";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(test);
sb.deleteCharAt(test.length()-2);
String newString = sb.toString();
```

Warning: This does not test for length before-hand but, that is what you asked for.

Comment: If you're going to take this approach, you should at least use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: -1 For concatenating a string in a loop. Use a StringBuilder.

Comment: @LordTorgamus Thanks, wasn't actually aware of String Builder, better?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö Also - was the issue with the loop that concatenation creates a new `String` each time?

Comment: @Alex Yes, when doing concatenating as you did the each time going through the loop you actually do this: theString = new StringBuilder(theString).append(addString).toString(); Removing my down vote since you had updated the answer.

Comment: Well, now you're not even using the looping method anymore, but yes, this is in fact better.

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = "abcde";
a = a.substring(0, a.length() - 2) + a.substring(a.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get last 2nd position = `str.length - 2;`

```
public static String removeCharAt(String s, int pos) {
       StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer( s.length() - 1 );
       buf.append( s.substring(0,pos) ).append( s.substring(pos+1) );
       return buf.toString();
}
```

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0030.html

Answer (score 0):

```
"abcde".replaceAll ("(.*).(.)", "$1$2")
```

It uses regex, searches for some characters which we want to refer to later as $1, plus one character to forget, and another, terminating character to remember as String 2 ($2).